# GSON help/Connecting to a web service (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am new to Android application building. I am trying to figure out how to send a response to a web service and validate the data. Here is my code:

---

LoginUser.java

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;



import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class LoginUser extends AppCompatActivity
{
// Progress Dialog Object
ProgressDialog prgDialog;
// Error Msg TextView Object
TextView errorMsg;
// Email Edit View Object
EditText emailET;
// Passwprd Edit View Object
EditText pwdET;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    // Find Error Msg Text View control by ID
    errorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);
    // Find Email Edit View control by ID
    emailET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtemail);
    // Find Password Edit View control by ID
    pwdET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtpass);
    // Instantiate Progress Dialog object
    prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Set Progress Dialog Text
    prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    // Set Cancelable as False
    prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
}




/**
 * Method gets triggered when Login button is clicked
 *
 * @param view
 */
public void loginUser(View view) {
    // Get Email Edit View Value
    String email = emailET.getText().toString();
    // Get Password Edit View Value
    String password = pwdET.getText().toString();

    // Instantiate Http Request Param Object
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

    // When Email Edit View and Password Edit View have values other than Null
    if (Utility.isNotNull(email) && Utility.isNotNull(password)) {
        // When Email entered is Valid
        if (Utility.validate(email)) {
            // Put Http parameter username with value of Email Edit         View control
            params.put("Username", email);
            // Put Http parameter password with value of Password Edit Value control
            params.put("Pass", password);
            // Invoke RESTful Web Service with Http parameters
            Login(params);
        }
        // When Email is invalid
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter valid email address with no spaces!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill the form, don't leave any field blank!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}



/**
 * Method that performs RESTful webservice invocations
 *
 * @param params
 */
public void Login(RequestParams params){
    // Show Progress Dialog
    prgDialog.show();

    // Make RESTful webservice call using AsyncHttpClient object
    final AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("MY URL IS HERE", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {



        // When the response returned by REST has Http response code '200'
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody)
        {

            // Hide Progress Dialog
            prgDialog.hide();
            try {

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new String(responseBody));

                // When the JSON response has status boolean value assigned with true
                if (obj.getBoolean("status")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are successfully logged in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Navigate to Home screen
                    navigatetoMyLocationActivity();
                }
                // Else display error message
                else {
                    errorMsg.setText(obj.getString("error_msg"));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),     obj.getString("error_msg"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occurred [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }


        // When the response returned by REST has Http response code other than '200'
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            // Hide Progress Dialog
            prgDialog.hide();
            // When Http response code is '404'
            if (statusCode == 404) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // When Http response code is '500'
            else if (statusCode == 500) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // When Http response code other than 404, 500
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occurred! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet or remote server is not up and running]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
}




/**
 * Method which navigates from Login Activity to Home Activity
 */
public void navigatetoMyLocationActivity(){
    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyLocation.class);
    homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(homeIntent);
  }
}
```

---

I also created a DTO but I am not sure if it is necessary or not but here is:

LoginUserDTO.java

```
public class LoginUserDTO
{
private String UserName;
private String Pass;


public LoginUserDTO(String UserName, String Pass)
 {
  this.UserName = UserName;
  this.Pass = Pass;

 }


public String getUsername()
{
    return UserName;
 }

public void setUserName(String UserName)
{
    this.UserName = UserName;
 }



public String getPass()
 {
    return Pass;
  }

public void setPass(String Pass)
  {
    this.Pass = Pass;
  }
}
```

---

I also have the internet permission in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

---

If someone could at least point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks in advance!

Comment: what error you are getting? post the error.

Comment: when I try to sign in on my emulator it is giving me the "Error Occurred [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!". @DevendraSingh

Comment: Could you debug and paste what `new String(responseBody)` returns?

Comment: Another thing I would like to say is that, if you have the time, try to use some existing HTTP client  , like Retrofit. http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: "org.json.JSONException: Value <HTML><HEAD><link of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject". That is the only string error I see. I also see "E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xadc33ca0" @LeonardoSibela

Comment: You could try to go to the URL in a browser or use a HTTP tool like Postman to make the request. Your server is returning HTML instead of JSON, so you need to figure out why that is before you start using Android to connect to it.

Comment: I posted a answer of what can help you. If you still can't understand, just let me know. I hope it helps :)

Comment: I read your response! Thank you! I am looking in the debugger console but nothing is coming up as far as the (new String(responseBody)); is concerned. I was told that I am missing a json parse but I have no clue how to implement that in my code. Also I have downloaded Postman but I don't know how to use it. I am new to Java and I've only been programming a couple of months. @LeonardoSibela

Comment: I will edit my answer to help you a little more :)

Comment: About the postman. That's a good way to test your server too. To understand how to use it, you'll have to learn how to make HTTP requests. Basicly, you have to put a URL that you wanna test, a HTTP METHOD (there are different methods GET (get info from server), POST (to insert data)...) and some other stuff like "What you expect to send or get" (Content-Type)... It's easy, once you know how to use it, I promisse :)

Comment: Hi, Can you post the URL if it's public? Maybe we can find the cause easily with that.
Thanks.

Comment: My friend, the code above is wrong. If you copied it, pay attention to the line `client.get("MY URL IS HERE", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {` Where "MY URL IS HERE" is, you should put a URL. But it's not that simple. You must have a real URL and since you are using the method get from `AsyncHttpClient`, you must be sure that this URL acept a GET HTTP METHOD and the params you are providing. I will, once again update my answer.

Comment: My real URL is in place of "MY URL IS HERE". If I provide it, you wouldn't be able to access it. @LeonardoSibela

Comment: My URL is not public. @RuchiraRandana

Comment: Debug your code and tell us everything is returning as that string

Comment: Also do I need a DTO? And if so is this how I call it from my LoginUser.java:    LoginUserDTO lUDTOs = new LoginUserDTO();
                    lUDTOs.getUsername();
                    lUDTOs.getPass(); @LeonardoSibela

Comment: In your case, you are not making use of your DTO, so, no, you don't need it. You should also study Object Oriented Programming. I think there are several things you gotta learn to understand everything that's happening, cause you are very confused. That's not bad or anything, it's just some concepts that you gotta learn first.

Comment: My facebook is the same as my name here "Leonardo Sibela". You could add me there, I could explain to you a bunch of stuff and then we could come back here so you could understand what's happening. Not the best thing ever on StackOverflow, but if you think it's okay......

Comment: I understand object oriented programming. I'm just confused about building mobile applications and connecting them to a web service. @LeonardoSibela

Comment: I don't have a Facebook account. @LeonardoSibela

Comment: @user6267535 if my answer helped you or if it is correct according to your question, please, considere accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your user get method for getting login.Instead use post()  method.

Comment: I am confused as to what you mean. Could you code it out? @Ram

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you commented, your API (server) is not sending a string Json but an HTLM page instead. Try to check what's wrong on your serverside.

You should understand that your JsonObject requires a String that reflects a Json and that the one you are trying to parse is not a Json, which causes the JSONException on your app. That's normal.

`JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("Hello");` // will throw a exception

`JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{name:lucas, 'age:25'}");` // is okay

If you don't know what a exception is, try to read some more about it :)

If the server you are getting it from is not yours, I sugest you to debug your code. If you don't know what debug means, is basicly the act of excuting your code and stop on certain lines to see your variables and understand what's happening. On android, yous should do something like:

1) Put a break point on line where you instantiate your Json by clicking on the left side of the line (you will notice a red ball where you clicked):
`JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new String(responseBody));`

2) Run your app on debug mode (hit the green bug button, instead of the play one).

3) Do whatever you have to do until the code get's to that particulary line.

4) Once the code is there, select the `new String(responseBody)` code, hit `CTRL + U` and evalute that String for more details about what your server is returning.

If you're still not being able to do it, try to learn how to debug a code, but I think that

I analised the code above and found a problem:
See the line bellow:

`client.get("MY URL IS HERE", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {`

Where "MY URL IS HERE" is, you should put a valid URL. But it's still not that simple. You must have a real URL and since you are using the method get from `AsyncHttpClient`, you must be sure that this URL accept a GET HTTP METHOD and the params you are providing.
The wrong URL is causing a web page to be returned since it does not exist.

I holp it helped :)